# Are >& and <& equivalent when duplicating descriptors in shell?

Tags: shell

In [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229677/bash-interactive-mode-on-redirect), the author said in comment:

> The <& or >& syntax are both using dup(2) or similar to clone the file descriptors. The only difference is that >& checks if the target file descriptor is open for writing, while <& checks if it's open for reading. In its default mode, a socket is open for both reading and writing, so both checks succeed, and the dup call is the same in either case.

I've tested duplicating descriptors of oridinary files and /dev/tcp sockets. Both operators made no difference, the only thing mattered when redirecting std* descriptors is the r/w permission specified when opening the file. And [bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) section 3.6.8 also says these two are different only when their lhs parameter is omitted.

My question is: does "check for r/w accessibility" part in the quote above really exist or some of my thinkings above are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The check indeed does not exist.

In `CWRU/posix-parser/make.c`, direction flags are stored (and later used in the event of an `open()` call in `redir.c`). However, in the codepaths which actually call `dup2()` in `redir.c`, the flags distinguishing between a file descriptor opened for read, write or read/write mode are never used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked bash source code and found that it also gives up this difference right before actual action. It's always a good idea to look up the code.